# Horizontal center text using objective-c / core graphics

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I'm trying to center a text on an iPhone screen using Core Graphics and I found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034940/draw-centered-text-using-core-graphics-mobile-device/).

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
NSString * text = @"text";
CGFloat minHeight = 40;
float widthIs = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, minHeight) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0] }
context:nil].size.width;
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1].CGColor);
[text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake((screenWidth - widthIs)/2, (screenHeight - minHeight)/2) withFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0]];
```

But trying this code for my own I can not really get it working. The text is not really centered on my screen and I have no idea how to edit the code to solve my problem.

This is the result I get:

[image]

Comment: Could you please update the code from above with your solution? Sorry I'm new in objective etc... :/ @Rob

Comment: When you say you found the answer in another StackOverflow question, please actually link to the question (or the answer directly).

Comment: Updated @DavidStockinger

Answer (score 0):

This looks basically right: A few minor observations:

1. Rather than referring to the `UIScreen`, I'd just refer to the view in which the text was rendered. E.g. if actually in some `UIView` subclass implementation, you'd just refer to `self.bounds.size`.
2. I would use the `attributes` rendition for not only getting the size of the bounding rect, but for `drawAtPoint`, too. E.g. Use `drawAtPoint:withAttributes:` instead of `drawAtPoint:withFont:`.
3. The font color should be part of the `attributes` dictionary, too.

For example:

```
CGSize viewSize = self.bounds.size;
NSString *text = @"text";
CGFloat minHeight = 40;
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]};
CGSize textSize = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, minHeight)
                                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                  attributes:attributes
                                     context:nil].size;
[text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake((viewSize.width - textSize.width)/2, (viewSize.height - textSize.height)/2) withAttributes:attributes];
```

If it's still not centered after you do this, you'd want to confirm the `frame` of the `UIView` in which you are  rendering this, and make sure the it is where you think it should be. You can run the app in the debugger and then use the view debugger [image: view debugger] to confirm where the view is located.

Answer (score 0):

Others have stated that your code is basically correct, so why is it not displaying the text where you expect?

My *guess* is that you are not drawing in the view you think you are and/or are confused over coordinate systems.

Using the current view's bounds instead of the screen will centre your text *in that view*, which is fine if the view itself is centered on the screen but would also display off centre if not.

You should figure out what view you are actually drawing in and/or read up on coordinate systems.

To draw the text in the centre of the screen regardless of the view you can calculate the origin as you have in *screen* coordinates and then convert it to the view's coordinates and draw there. E.g. if your code is inside a view's `drawRect` then something like:

```
// Save the point in screen coordinates 
CGPoint onScreenOrigin = CGPointMake((screenWidth - widthIs)/2, (screenHeight - minHeight)/2);
// Convert from screen to current view's coordinates
CGPoint inViewOrigin = [self convertPoint:onScreenOrigin fromView:nil];
// Draw the text
[text drawAtPoint:inViewOrigin ...];
```

This will draw the text in the centre of the screen regardless of the size and position of the view - provided of course that the view covers the area of the screen where the text needs to be, if it doesn't the text will be cropped to the view and may incomplete or completely invisible!

HTH

Comment: In this day and age of split screen multitasking, I don't think you ever want to use screen dimensions to figure out where anything goes...

Comment: @Rob - Fair point, the OP would be better using the main view of the storyboard. But either way it looks like the OP is either not drawing in the view they think they are or are drawing in the wrong coordinate system for the view - which is why their text is off centre. Just using the view bounds won't neccesarily fix that (e.g. if the view is not centred).

Comment: I'd quibble on the details (what about split view controllers or other view controller containment scenarios), but I absolutely agree with your diagnosis that it's likely a coordinate system translation error.